# Is there a way to place ngx bootstrap datepicker to the bottom right of input box?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

There is a way to place datepicker to the bottom left by assigning "bottom left" to "placement" attribute of ngx bootstrap datepicker. Similarly, do we have a way to place it at the right bottom. I tried placement="right bottom" but that didn't work

[I am getting something like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcdqb.png)

[but I need something like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QguiY.png)

Comment: Have you tried "bottom right" instead of "right bottom"?

Comment: it seems to work, would you pleas provide more code or make a sample stackblitz.

Comment: @FatemeFazli I have updated the description. There are 2 links attached now. first one is what I get and the second is what I need. Please check

Comment: @ArpitMeena yes I did